# How to reduce these values as much as possible

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following PHP core code below.

How I can use `for` function to reduce this code?

```
<?php
$a_b_x_01 = '0';
$a_b_x_02 = '18';
$a_b_x_03 = '36';
$a_b_x_04 = '54';
$a_b_x_05 = '72';
$a_b_x_06 = '90';
$a_b_x_07 = '108';
$a_b_x_08 = '126';
$a_b_x_09 = '144';
$a_b_x_10 = '162';
$a_b_x_11 = '180';
$a_b_x_12 = '198';
$a_b_x_13 = '216';
$a_b_x_14 = '234';
$a_b_x_15 = '252';
$a_b_x_16 = '270';
$a_b_x_17 = '288';
$a_b_x_18 = '306';
$a_b_x_19 = '324';
$a_b_x_20 = '342';
$a_b_x_21 = '360';
$a_b_x_22 = '378';
$a_b_x_23 = '396';
$a_b_x_24 = '414';

$a_b_y_01 = '108';
$a_b_y_02 = '0';
$a_b_y_03 = '18';
$a_b_y_04 = '36';
$a_b_y_05 = '54';
$a_b_y_06 = '72';
$a_b_y_07 = '90';

$a_b_xy_01_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_02_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_03_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_04_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_05_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_06_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_07_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_08_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_09_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_10_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_11_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_12_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_13_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_14_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_15_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_16_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_17_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_18_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_19_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_20_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_21_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_22_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_23_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_01;
$a_b_xy_24_01 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_01;

$a_b_xy_01_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_02_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_03_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_04_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_05_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_06_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_07_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_08_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_09_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_10_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_11_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_12_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_13_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_14_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_15_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_16_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_17_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_18_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_19_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_20_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_21_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_22_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_23_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_02;
$a_b_xy_24_02 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_02;

$a_b_xy_01_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_02_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_03_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_04_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_05_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_06_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_07_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_08_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_09_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_10_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_11_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_12_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_13_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_14_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_15_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_16_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_17_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_18_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_19_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_20_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_21_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_22_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_23_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_03;
$a_b_xy_24_03 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_03;

$a_b_xy_01_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_02_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_03_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_04_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_05_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_06_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_07_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_08_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_09_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_10_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_11_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_12_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_13_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_14_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_15_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_16_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_17_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_18_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_19_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_20_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_21_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_22_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_23_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_04;
$a_b_xy_24_04 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_04;

$a_b_xy_01_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_02_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_03_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_04_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_05_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_06_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_07_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_08_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_09_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_10_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_11_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_12_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_13_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_14_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_15_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_16_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_17_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_18_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_19_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_20_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_21_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_22_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_23_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_05;
$a_b_xy_24_05 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_05;

$a_b_xy_01_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_02_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_03_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_04_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_05_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_06_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_07_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_08_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_09_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_10_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_11_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_12_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_13_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_14_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_15_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_16_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_17_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_18_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_19_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_20_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_21_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_22_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_23_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_06;
$a_b_xy_24_06 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_06;

$a_b_xy_01_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_01.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_02_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_02.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_03_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_03.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_04_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_04.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_05_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_05.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_06_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_06.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_07_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_07.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_08_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_08.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_09_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_09.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_10_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_10.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_11_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_11.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_12_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_12.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_13_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_13.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_14_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_14.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_15_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_15.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_16_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_16.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_17_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_17.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_18_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_18.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_19_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_19.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_20_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_20.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_21_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_21.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_22_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_22.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_23_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_23.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
$a_b_xy_24_07 = 'x='.$a_b_x_24.' y='.$a_b_y_07;
?>
```

*Example text because I have too much code. Example text because I have too much code. Example text because I have too much code. Example text because I have too much code. Example text because I have too much code. Example text because I have too much code.*

Comment: "Example text because I have too much code.(more spam) Example text because I have too much code." No you have to less explaination thats is the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a_b_x = [0, 18, 36 ...];
$a_b_y = [108, 0, 18 ...];

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($a_b_x);$i++){

     $arr =[];
     for($j=0;$j<sizeof($a_b_y);$j++){

            array_push($arr,"x=".$a_b_x[$i]." y=".$a_b_y[$j]);
     }
     array_push($a_b_xy,$arr);
}
```

for display use:

```
  for($i =0; $i<sizeof($a_b_xy);$i++){

     for($j=0;$J<sizeof($a_b_xy[$i]);$j++){
          echo $a_b_xy[$i][$j]."<br/>";
     }
  }
```